# Using an animated GIF in a Dialog loading screen. JSF 1.1

Tags: jsf

This problem is the result of IE7 not displaying animated GIF's that are hidden.

for reference:
http://crunchlife.com/articles/2008/06/11/ie7s-inanimate-gif

These 2 solutions involve the use of the setTimeout function and innerHTML. These examples use absolute URL's to the images.  Since I'm using JSF, I would like to use relative URL's.  Is there a proper way to do this in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

Those examples doesn't use absolute URL's. Your problem lies somewhere else. At least, the URL pointing to the image should be relative to the request URL of the JSF page in question. You can easily check it in the browser's address bar.

A common mistake among starters is namely that they think that it should be relative to the location of the page in the server side folder structure. This is untrue. You should look at the request URL. Determine the absolute request URL of both the JSF page and the image, then you should be able to extract the relative URL to the image from it.